# oct2py failes to init with WinError 5 access denied

Tags: python, miniconda, oct2py

I have installed miniconda python version 3.6.1.
conda,python,oct2py and all dependencies packages are up to date.

Both python and octave are installed using 64 bit windows binary installers.

In python script

I only use

```
from oct2py import octave
```

and I get the following error trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/t-avben/PycharmProjects/TailGrpDelayAnalysis/main.py", line 7, in <module>
from oct2py import octave
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oct2py\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
octave = Oct2Py()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 73, in __init__
self.restart()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 508, in restart
logger=self.logger)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 144, in __init__
self.repl = self._create_repl()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 338, in _create_repl
version = subprocess.check_output(version_cmd).decode('utf-8')
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I changed the octave binary folder permissions to full access for all users,
and disabled windows UAC.

any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I have set the octave environemnt variable to octave.exe.
Now I have another weird error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 99, in expect_loop
incoming = spawn.read_nonblocking(spawn.maxread, timeout)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py", line 66, in read_nonblocking
raise EOF('End Of File (EOF).')
pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/t-avben/PycharmProjects/TailGrpDelayAnalysis/main.py", line 7, in <module>
from oct2py import octave
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oct2py\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
octave = Oct2Py()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 73, in __init__
self.restart()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 508, in restart
logger=self.logger)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 144, in __init__
self.repl = self._create_repl()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 352, in _create_repl
stdin_prompt_regex=STDIN_PROMPT_REGEX)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\metakernel\replwrap.py", line 90, in __init__
continuation_prompt_regex))
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\metakernel\replwrap.py", line 110, in set_prompt
self.child.expect(prompt_regex)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 321, in expect
timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 345, in expect_list
return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 105, in expect_loop
return self.eof(e)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 50, in eof
raise EOF(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF).
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x00000184A0CF0240>
searcher: searcher_re:
0: re.compile("octave.*>")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied python using moviepy to write gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif)

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Python36\` is a weird location for anaconda install. Did you explicitly install it there or did you install python 3.6 separately?

Comment: @NehalJWani I installed python 3.6 separately. I solved the issue by canceling the read-only flag from octave vbase dir and explicitly setting OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE ENV to octave-cli.exe