# How do i overcome a permissions error

Tags: python, permissions

Hello i am trying to delete a directory which is like a temporary file storage. however it does not work and keeps throwing the same erros

```
     directory = ("C:\\Users\\Bradley\\Desktop\\Log in system\\TempFiles")
     os.remove(directory)
```

here is the error:

```
     PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 
     'C:\\Users\\Bradley\\Desktop\\Log in system\\TempFiles'
```

Comment: Are there any files in the directory? They would need removing first.

Comment: Then you need to have this permission to delete the directory.

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your permissions
2. `os.remove` requires a file path, and raises OSError if path is a
   directory. If path is a directory, OSError is raised; see `rmdir()`
   below to remove a directory.

   Try this:

   ```
   os.rmdir("C:\\Users\\Bradley\\Desktop\\Log in system\\TempFiles")
   ```
3. In other way you can use this trick ;) :

   ```
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'Your command'])
   ```

And, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801762/3131945) post, you can run your program as an administrator by right click and run as administrator.

Comment: I just tried implementing it into my code and it has come back saying that the directory does not exist when it actually does?