# Permission denied when pandas dataframe to tempfile csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, temporary-files

I'm trying to store a pandas dataframe to a tempfile in csv format (in windows), but am being hit by:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpweymbkye'

```
import tempfile
import pandas

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    df.to_csv(temp.name)
```

Where df is the dataframe. I've also tried changing the temp directory to one I am sure I have write permissions:

```
tempfile.tempdir='D:/Username/Temp/'
```

This gives me the same error message

Edit:

The tempfile appears to be locked for editing as when I change the loop to:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    df.to_csv(temp.name + '.csv')
```

I can write the file in the temp directory, but then it is not automatically deleted at the end of the loop, as it is no longer a temp file.

However, if I change the code to:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv') as temp:
    training_data.to_csv(temp.name)
```

I get the same error message as before. The file is not open anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know enough about tempfile module to give a proper answer. 
But have a look here (final post): https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1047

just do     df.to_csv(temp)    (without .name)

Comment: I think that's a typo in his code, that returns this error: "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: Did you mistakenly leave the file open? This will give you the same error.

Comment: I think that is what is happening, as I get the same behaviour when I add the suffix .csv in NamedTemporaryFile, but I am not opening the file anywhere else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your permissions and, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801762/3131945) post, you can run your program as an administrator by right click and run as administrator.

We can use the to_csv command to do export a DataFrame in CSV format. Note that the code below will by default save the data into the current working directory. We can save it to a different folder by adding the foldername and a slash to the file

```
verticalStack.to_csv('foldername/out.csv').
```

Check out your working directory to make sure the CSV wrote out properly, and that you can open it! If you want, try to bring it back into python to make sure it imports properly.

```
newOutput = pd.read_csv('out.csv', keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""])
```

[ref](http://chris.friedline.net/2015-12-15-rutgers/lessons/python2/04-merging-data.html)

Unlike `TemporaryFile()`, the user of `mkstemp()` is responsible for deleting the temporary file when done with it.

With the use of this function may introduce a security hole in your program. By the time you get around to doing anything with the file name it returns, someone else may have beaten you to the punch. `mktemp()` usage can be replaced easily with `NamedTemporaryFile()`, passing it the `delete=False` paramete.

[Read more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

After export to `CSV` you can close your file with `temp.close()`.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp:
    df.to_csv(temp.name + '.csv')
    temp.close()
```

Comment: Running as admin didn't change anything, and I tried changing the tempdir to one where I definitely have write permission

Comment: @thebigspin I changed my answer

Comment: @thebigspin try this: with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp:

Comment: This works (not sure why!?) but then the file isn't deleted at the end of the loop. Tried adding os.remove(temp.name) but then it says file is in use...

Comment: @thebigspin I changed my answer. please close your file before delete.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include only the relevant info (adding delete=false and then temp.close() after using the file) in case someone else hits the same problem?

Comment: @thebigspin I add this part and make answer like as step-to-step guide for this error :)

Comment: `NamedTemporaryFile` has a kwarg `suffix` which you can set to `.csv` so that you just have to use `temp.name` in your answer.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same error message and the issue was resolved after adding "/df.csv" to file_path.

```
df.to_csv('C:/Users/../df.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: This would create a permanent csv file (`df.csv`) and not a tempfile

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, it gives that error simply because there is another file with the same name and it has no permission to delete the earlier file and replace it with the new file.

1. So either name the file differently while saving it,
   or
2. If you are working on Jupyter Notebook or a other similar environment, delete the file after executing the cell that reads it into memory. So that when you execute the cell which writes it to the machine, there is no other file that exists with that name.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes，you need check the file path that if you have right permission to read and write file. Especially when you use relative path.

```
xxx.to_csv('%s/file.csv'%(file_path), index = False)
```

Comment: make sure to CHMOD the folder you are writing to (777)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. I simply had not yet saved my entire python file. Once I saved my python file in VS code as "insertyourfilenamehere".py to documents(which is in my path), I ran my code again and I was able to save my data frame as a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, this error pops up when one attempt to save the file that have been saved already and currently open in the background.

You may try closing those files first and then rerun the code.

Answer (score -6):

Just give a valid path and a file name

e.g:

```
final_df.to_csv('D:\Study\Data Science\data sets\MNIST\sample.csv')
```

Comment: This is not saving to a tempfile and so does not address the question