# Error when installing Pygame (1.9.3) on Windows

Tags: python, pygame

This question has been asked a lot around the Internet but until now I haven't found someone who's getting the same error as I am (maybe I'm not looking hard enough, who knows).

I'm using a Windows 10 64-bit Acer laptop (I don't know any other specs, it isn't mine) and trying to install *pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl* (I've been told it's better to get the 32-bit versions of both Python and Pygame). I receive this error when I go into PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts> pip3 install pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Processing c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\scripts\pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pygame'
```

Not too sure what's going on. If anyone *does*, thanks so much in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801762/6220679

Comment: @skrx There is no "Run as Administrator" option, let alone "Run," no matter where I right-click.

Comment: Right-click on cmd or powershell.

Comment: @skrx Oh my God thank you, I feel like an idiot now.

Comment: No problemo. Can happen to all of us. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems like a permission issue so try to run it as admin. In case it doesn't work this is my advise:

I have always had issues installing python libs in windows until I found this repo, it has never let me down. I have installed pygame from here like 20 times and always works. Try it and let me know:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: You are on the right path then. Open the terminal (cmd) as admin and try again.

Comment: No problem, nice to help ;-)