# Python programming mrjob package permission error

Tags: python

I am kinda new to python programming so excuse me if i ask something for which the answer is obvious. I wanted to run a map reduce program so i install the mrjob package as needed. Now, when i try to run the sample program given:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, line):
    yield "chars", len(line)
    yield "words", len(line.split())
    yield "lines", 1

def reducer(self, key, values):
    yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

I get an error saying Win error 5 permission denied and then printing the path where app data is stored. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the underscores

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

Comment: oh thank you for the quick answer, that was not the issue tho:
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for inline runner
Running step 1 of 1...
Creating temp directory C:\Users\kkiri\AppData\Local\Temp\mrpython.kkiri.20180312.161319.365500
Streaming final output from C:\Users\kkiri\AppData\Local\Temp\mrpython.kkiri.20180312.161319.365500\output...

Comment: the error is huge so the last line of it is this one-->PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\kkiri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\mrpython.kkiri.20180312.161319.365500\\step\\000\\cache\\mrpython.py'

Comment: Since it's a permission error try running the code with sudo. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif

Comment: I have already tried running the script as admin but it won't work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

My resolution via this Github [ticket I submitted to Yelp/MrJob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/1800):

**Issue**

Running MRJob 0.6.3 in a python 3.6.x installation will produce the following error (similar to my local Windows machine):

`Removing temp directory C:\temp\app.{UserName}.20180707.222938.021378...
[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\temp\\app.{UserName}.20180707.222938.021378\\step\\000\\cache\\app.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\temp\\app.{UserName}.20180707.222938.021378\\step\\000\\cache\\app.py'`

**Attempts**
1. Tried running CLI as administrator
2. Tried changing temporary folder TEMP
3. `pip uninstall mrjob` and then did `pip install mrjob==0.5.10`

**Resolution**
The 3rd attempt worked. By going through and installing the MRJob version 0.5.10, latest in [documentation here](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/), I got my application to work.