# PermissionError while running python program on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I've been tinkering with the os module for a few days encountered this error. Can't seem to fix it.
Here is an example:

```
import os


os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop')

os.rename('odin', 'ddin')

print (os.listdir())
```

And this is the error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'odin' -> 'ddin'
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied python using moviepy to write gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif)

Answer (score 0):

you are running your python program from an user that does not have permissions to change the specific file name ' try running from another user or change the file permissions to allow writing to your user.

Answer (score 0):

First, try running the same program in IDLE with administrator privileges.
Second, There is chance that your anti-virus software is blocking your python script so try disabling antivirus.