# Python multiprocessing. Attribute Error: can't pickle local object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm learning a multiprocessing and have one problem:

```
[0120/214250.476:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(967)] Lost UI shared 
context.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:26840/devtools/browser/82bab26a-25fa- 
4e67-84d9-ae52ebfbdcae
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaBrut.py", line 70, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron. 
<locals>.encodekey'

E:\PyInstaBrut>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denined
```

I read this error, but I don't understand nothing.
The function is standard: has several arguments (but I don't want to show code by some reasons), but a part of it looks like a  `Process(target=func, args=(arg0, arg1, arg2))`. I start process after `if __name__=="__main__":` structure and start in the shell, so I don't know how solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PermissionError: \[WinError 5\] Access is denied python using moviepy to write gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif)