# How can I find where a windows program is installed using only its full name? (And the name of his executable)

Tags: python, windows, directory, find

I'm creating a program that recognizes my voice saying: Open * name of a program * and it opens the program.
I have a script to decrypt the name of all installed programs, but I do not know how to get what I want by taking this information.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as s:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)
    while True:
        audio = r.listen(s)
        try:
            speech = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-US')
            speech = str(speech)
            speech = speech.lower()
            print('Você disse: ' + speech)
            if 'bash' in speech:
                #Should open the GitBash
            if 'mozilla' in speech:
                #Should open the Mozilla
        except:
            pass
```

I hope the program opens the program to speak

Comment: You could make the script loop over the programs in paths defined in env variables.

Comment: I am a beginner in programming ... I do not know how I would do this..

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to open the program from the command line, we can use the OS package to run these commands. Hope this helps!

```
import os
os.system("COMMAND TO OPEN PROGRAM FROM COMMAND LINE")
```

We need a way to list all of the files in a particular directory (programs directory in this case) The following code helps us do this.

```
import os
def listAllFiles(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        return [ path ]
    else:
        files = [ ]
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            files += listAllFiles(path + "/" + filename)
        return files

print(listAllFiles("Documents"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately to open a specific program by cmd, I need to know the directory where the EXE program is, but thanks!

Comment: Edited the post. Now you can list all files in a directory (it finds nested files too, so you can call this program from the home directory). It prints out the path to the file too! Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried to use this code, but when I sent the C: / Program Files directory, I received the error:                                                          File "C:/Users/Guilherme/Documents/Repositorios/AssistenteVirtual/outro.py", line 15, in listAllFiles
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado: 'C:/Program Files/Arquivos Comuns'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif