# cannot install tensoflow-gpu

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

I have been tying to install tensorflow gpu via pip and I keep on getting the error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError:

[WinError 5] Access is denied:
'C:\\Users\\shahm\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\compiler\\tf2tensorrt\\_pywrap_py_utils.pyd'

Check the permissions.
```

I have triend both adding the `--user` flag and running powershell and command prompt as administrator. Any Ideas?

Comment: Looks like there *may* be some possible solutions here, though the scenario is somewhat different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @manavshah, please follow the steps mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) to install tensorflow-gpu and let us know if you require any further assistance. Thank you!